# Geometry Nodes curve interaction not making sense to me

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: with this setup, those plates there scale correctly along the curve, but don't rotate correctly along it, this doesn't make sense to me]

with this setup, those plates there scale correctly along the curve, but don't rotate correctly along it, this doesn't make sense to me

[image: routing the curve through a point generator gets the rotation to work correctly, but for obvious reasons, now there is no spline to draw the factor variable from, making the scaling no longer work]

routing the curve through a point generator gets the rotation to work correctly, but for obvious reasons, now there is no spline to draw the factor variable from, making the scaling no longer work

my question is why, in the 1st scenario, does the rotation not correctly obtain its data from the points
thanks in advance to anyone offering assistence

Answer (score 1):

It's always right after you finally ask the question that you figure it out.

[image]

Edit: Saw that it was requested so edit.
Using Curve to points will mean no have no curve to reference when you need it later. So sticking with resample curve was the only way I figured out how to do it.
Using Curve tangent-> Rotate Euler to vector-> Rotate Euler, into the rotation input of instance on points solved it for me.

Thought the image was clear.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you figured out? Since this site is aiming to provide sustainable answers for future users that might have the same/similar problem. Having to look through all the nodes to find out what you changed (or why) is not really easy.